# What are clan tags for in Call of Duty - Black Ops?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

Other than being a set of characters next to your name what is its function? Does it do anything like automatically group you with members of your clan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *clan* is an affiliation of people that generally play together. A *clan tag* is a set of characters that identifies your affiliation with a particular clan.

Comment: So are you saying is it is no more than a set of characters next to your name? Clan tags have no functionality within the game?

Comment: @Clark: No functionality, they just let other people know that you're part of a clan (or just being funny by putting a humorous tag before your name).

Comment: Like the clan tag [POOP]mipadi, for example